# How to integrate maven-surefire-report-plugin into maven-site-plugin using report-only goal

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-site-plugin

I have the following issue:

The maven-surefire-report-plugin invokes the lifecycle goal `test`. This starts my testrunner again. To prevent this, they made this workaround:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-257

I am now encountering difficulties implementing this into my POM.
They have the following note on the page:

> Note: As of version 2.8 this plugin requires Maven Site Plugin 2.1 or
>   higher to work properly. Version 2.7.2 and older are still compatible
>   with newer surefire versions, so mixing is possible.

My maven runs: "clean deploy site-deploy"

This is my POM part:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <reportPlugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                </configuration>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>index</report>
                            <report>dependencies</report>
                            <report>project-team</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site</outputDirectory>
                    <reportsDirectories>
                        <reportsDirectories>${project.build.directory}/site/surefire-reports</reportsDirectories>
                    </reportsDirectories>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </reportPlugins>
        <generateReports>true</generateReports>
        <inputEncoding>UTF-8</inputEncoding>
        <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

How do I configure it that only `surefire-report:report-only` is triggered and the `test`-phase is not invoked (but do everything else is done in `site`-phase)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching the internet for a few hours and some things I finally found out how.

The goal has to be the report, like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site</outputDirectory>
        <reportsDirectories>
            <reportsDirectories>${project.build.directory}/site/surefire-reports</reportsDirectories>
        </reportsDirectories>
    </configuration>
    <reportSets>
        <reportSet>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <reports>
                <report>report-only</report>
            </reports>
        </reportSet>
    </reportSets>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Works for me too!  It also worked without the line `<id>integration-tests</id>`, and I didn't need the `<configuration>` section either (because I hadn't changed the directories from the defaults).